# Multi-core simulators/emulators advice

Tags: embedded, arm, multiprocessing, embedded-linux, multicore

Just want to know if there are any good simulators/emulators I can use to simulate a multi-core system on a standard desktop PC (Intel Core i3, 4 GB RAM etc.)

Need to experiment on:

- Implementing a 2x2-4x4 Network on chip based multi-core system (cores can be low end ARM cores for example; homogenous)
- Performance is an issue (so I think Qemu isn't going to work)
- Need to run uCLinux/FreeRTOS (or some small footprint OS) on top of the above cores (experiment with shared mem/distributed mem/MPI mechanisms)
- Looked at OVPSim, seems interesting, any downsides?
- Simulators should be fast! As I will be modifying the kernels to perform some algorithms. So not cycle accurate of course, but maybe instruction accurate.

Finally, once the simulations are complete, I will be testing on FPGA.

Any sort of ideas are welcome!

Comment: If you are trying to look at distributed mem / shared mem, and effects of network on chip topologies, then I would think you do need a cycle accurate simulation.  If it's only instruction accurate you won't see any effects from memory latency.

Comment: I'll be very impressed if you can find a fast multicore cycle-accurate emulator.

Comment: What's your budget?  There are commercial offerings that do this, but they are Not Cheap.

Comment: @tc. : Not hard to find; my company (Mentor Graphics) sells one.  See http://www.techdesignforums.com/practice/technique/emulation-delivers-energy-efficiencies-and-economies-of-scale/.  It's a box the size of a large closet, and costs a few million dollars -- but it also does multicore cycle-accurate simulations pretty darn quick.  For the original poster's use, though, there are probably software solutions that are good enough.

Comment: @BrooksMoses I meant within the poster's constraints ("on a standard desktop PC"), but am nevertheless rather impressed!

Comment: If you are going to implement on FPGAs anyway, maybe you could do that from the start (using available cores), and build in hardware-assisted instrumentation comparable to what you would get from the desired simulator.